# Как получить корректную ширину и величину окна?

Tags: java, классы, gui

Пару дней назад начал делать приложение java GUI. У меня есть три класса, 
`MainClass`, `SimpleWind`, `Calculations`. В первом классе я инициализурую окно, добавляю кнопки. Во втором классе я рисую  некоторые геометрические фигуры, обрабатываю клики. В третьем классе я провожу некоторые исчисления, используя данные, которые дают функции getWitdth() и getHeight(). Но, используя их, программа получает значения высоты и ширины, равные нулю.

```
   public class MainClass extends JFrame{
        Calculations calc = new Calculations(this);
        SimpleWind s = new SimpleWind(this);
    MainClass(String str)
    {
        //....тут инициализация окна, кнопки, менеджер расположения и т.д.
        this.setSize(800, 800);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Класс, где я провожу исчисления, используя оставшуюся рабочую область окна.

```
public class Calculations {
    public static int Array[][];
    public static int n;
    MainClass var;
public Calculations(MainClass obj)
{
    var = obj;
    randgen();
}
public void randgen() 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("123 it is working");
        n = in.nextInt();
        Array=new int[n][2];
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            Array[i][0] = (int)(Math.random()*var.getWidth()+0);
            Array[i][1] = (int)(Math.random()*var.getHeight()+0);
            System.out.println("x"+i+" = "+Array[i][0]+ ", y"+i+" = "+ Array[i][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас выводит ноль, потому как по правилам инициализация переменной `calc` происходит перед тем, как Ваш layout будет сформирован и отрисован. Следовательно пока он не построен, то и все значения остаются нулевыми. 
Для того, чтобы получить реальные значения окна, инициализация переменной следует производить после того, как будет построен UI:

```
MainClass(String str)
{
     //....тут инициализация окна, кнопки, менеджер расположения и т.д.
     this.setSize(800, 800);
     this.setVisible(true);
     calc = new Calculations(this);
}
```

Плюс ко всему мне кажется, что само по себе окно у Вас строится не того размера, как Вы задаете. Ниже приведен пример кода, который точно использует заданный размер окна:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    Calculations calc;

    public Test() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        calc = new Calculations(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}

class Calculations {
    public static int array[][];
    public static int n;
    Test var;

    public Calculations(Test obj) {
        var = obj;
        randgen();
    }

    public void randgen() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("123 it is working");
        n = in.nextInt();
        array = new int[n][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i][0] = (int) (Math.random() * var.getWidth() + 0);
            array[i][1] = (int) (Math.random() * var.getHeight() + 0);
            System.out.println("x" + i + " = " + array[i][0] + ", y" + i + " = " + array[i][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь это поможет понять проблему.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так `var.getContentPane().getWidth()`

Comment: Результат тот же.